# Screen randomly turning off and on and erratically responsive touchpad and keyboard

Tags: screen, flicker

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a [Trekstor Primetab T13B,][1] alongside with the pre-installed Windows 10. When using Ubuntu, the laptop works 100% fine for some time -ranging from a few minutes to several hours- until both touchpad and keyboard suddenly become erratically responsive. This is immediately followed by the screen randomly turning off and on. Please note that the laptop obviously does not crash, as I am still able to power it off or reboot it in a terminal, whilst screen keeps flickering heavily. Apart from restarting the computer, the only way to recover from this issue is to plug an external monitor to the HDMI port. Then everything immediately gets back to normal. For this reason I suspect an issue with some graphic driver or settings. However I have not seen anything strange in the logs. So I am a bit puzzled.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Adding output as requested by heynnema :

```
    #free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       452Mi       2.6Gi        82Mi       628Mi       2.9Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

```
    #df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1897360       0   1897360   0% /dev
tmpfs             384956    1632    383324   1% /run
/dev/sda2      114337956 7754020 100732800   8% /
tmpfs            1924768   62592   1862176   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1924768       0   1924768   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2          4352    4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop1         45312   45312         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop3         91264   91264         0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop0        153600  153600         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop4          1024    1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop5         55936   55936         0 100% /snap/core18/1279
/dev/loop6         55936   55936         0 100% /snap/core18/1223
/dev/loop7          4096    4096         0 100% /snap/hw-probe/551
/dev/loop8        160512  160512         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop9          4352    4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop10         4096    4096         0 100% /snap/hw-probe/616
/dev/loop11        15104   15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop12        91264   91264         0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop13        15104   15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/mmcblk0p1     98304   76287     22017  78% /boot/efi
tmpfs             384952      28    384924   1% /run/user/1000
```

```
    #df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      114337956 7754828 100731992   8% /
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `df`.